# What is the effect of more than one chance of selection when sampling?

Tags: sample, weights, weighted-data, survey-sampling

I am designing a clustered sample. Within each cluster there are 3 groups that will be sampled from - two at a higher rate than the other. The two subgroups that will be sampled at a higher rate are also a part of the third group, so they are being oversampled and will need to be weighted for analyses on the entire sample.

Say g1 and g2 are the subgroups that will be oversampled, and g3 is the other group. Say g1 and g2 are sampled from at some rate (higher than the rate for g3), and then the remaining g1 and g2 are added back into g3 and the sample from g3 is drawn.

So the samples from g1 and g2 would be a mix of those that were sampled from those groups in the first instance, and those that were sampled from g3.

When it comes to data preparation, calculating weights for the two subgroups will be a bit more complicated, as there's an extra probability of selection to take into account for some of them.

Besides the extra weighting work, is there anything else I need to take into account due to some units having an additional chance of being selected? Is there anything wrong with this methodology?